# How to redirect or show custom error message?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to show custom error page when the DB server down,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `error pages` in the framework. It is located under **`application/views/errors/html`** there's a file named `db_error.php` folder. I think that's where you are looking for based on the question and image you posted. You can manipulate those page and customize the design of the page. You can also refer to the guide [here.](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html)